# The "Python" command requires the command line developer tools loop with Xcode 13.4.1 on macOS 12.5

Tags: python, xcode, macos, nativescript, xcode-command-line-tools

My setup is 2021 MBP with M1 Pro processor, macOS 12.5 and Xcode 13.4.1. I'm building an app using NativeScript and I can't release the app because every time I go to `product` > `archive` Xcode says "Python command requires the command line tools." When I agree to install it will look like it installed but then start over.

I reset my Mac and reinstalled macOS so a fresh setup was used. First I followed the suggestion from NativeScript docs (https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-ios) and ran `sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python` which created an alias for python 2.x. Then did `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and `python3 -m pip install six`. Tested my configuration with `ns doctor ios` - it complained about missing python and Xcode dialog prompted me to install python. Click install, it finishes, running `ns doctor ios` and starting over.

While it seems like macOS 12.5 ships with python3 already none of the options worked me.

Later found an article where the author suggested installing python using `pyenv`. So I went that path, installed it globally and set env into my shell. Retested and got the same error.

`Xcode-select -p` results in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

I tried:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python
```

None helped. I also tried

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3.8 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python
```

as I noticed there's python3.8 in Xcode's folder but that didn't work either. I'm a bit confused why Xcode is looking for Xcode in it's own folder now and doesn't use python3 that comes with macOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a fix.

Steps I did to make it work:

1. Removed all symlinks I've set originally
2. Removed python installed via `pyenv` using `pyenv uninstall 3.10.6`
3. Ran `brew uninstall pyenv` to remove`pyenv`
4. `brew install python`
5. `python --version` results in `Python 3.9.13`
6. And finally `sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python`

So essentially if you're on a new system do steps 4 and 6 and you should be good to go.

Comment: hmm, dunno. When I run `python -v` after installing it (python didn't seem to exist, so I only did steps 4 and 6 initially), it get a big error output saying Xcode couldn't find python and the prompt appears again

Comment: ooo, actually, `python3 --version` works, as opposed to `python --version`

Comment: It looks like I also needed to open up Xcode to install some additional components

Answer (score 2):

Before anything, please ensure to fully remove pyenv from your system.

This is what helped me:

1. Confirm you have this commandLineTools installed:

```
xcode-select -p
```

2. Next confirm there is no 'python' exec in the .../bin file of that dir (you should have python3, etc. in the folder, though):

```
ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ | grep python
```

3. Finally, if 'python' doesn't exist, add a symLink entry for 'python':

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python
```

credit: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704099?answerId=719739022#719739022